# How to convert the SQL Row to Column with dynamic rows and column

Tags: sql-server, database

I am stuck in creation of one report which is basically a TAT report.

We have a Table A which has all the data where we have case no., username, queuename, How much minute user has keep opened the case in the given queue. Below might be the combination:

Case 1 might have passed from queue1, queue2
Case 2 might have passed from queue1, queue3
User1 can open Case1 multiple time in the same queue
User 2 can open Case 1 multiple time in the same queue
I already have the calculation for how much time duration (in minutes) did the given user opened the case on the specific queue. Below is the sample data:

| Case | Queue | User | TAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COB-0000000001-process | Branch_Maker | User A | 90 |
| COB-0000000001-process | Branch_Maker | User B | 122 |
| COB-0000000001-process | Branch_Maker | User A | 25 |
| COB-0000000001-process | Branch_Maker | User C | 27 |
| COB-0000000001-process | Branch_Maker | User D | 30 |
| COB-0000000001-process | Branch_Maker | User A | 40 |
| COB-0000000001-process | Branch_Checker | User A | 120 |
| COB-0000000001-process | Branch_Checker | User E | 100 |
| COB-0000000004-process | Compliance | User F | 10 |
| COB-0000000004-process | Compliance | User A | 15 |
| COB-0000000004-process | Compliance | User B | 20 |
| COB-0000000004-process | Branch_Maker | User A | 20 |
| COB-0000000004-process | Branch_Checker | User H | 10 |
| COB-0000000004-process | Branch_Checker | User A | 15 |
| COB-0000000004-process | Director | User M | 20 |
| COB-0000000004-process | Director | User N | 23 |
| COB-0000000004-process | LPD | User O | 20 |
| COB-0000000004-process | RCD | User J | 30 |

I need something like below:

| Case | Branch_Maker User | Branch_Maker TAT | Branch_Checker User | Branch_Checker TAT | Compliance User | Compliance TAT | Director User | Director TAT | LPD User | LPD TAT | RCD User | RCD TAT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| COB-0000000001-process | User A | 155 | User A | 120 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000001-process | User B | 122 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000001-process | User C | 27 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000001-process | User D | 30 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000001-process |  |  | User E | 100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000004-process | User A | 20 | User A | 15 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000004-process |  |  |  |  | User F | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000004-process |  |  |  |  | User A | 15 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000004-process |  |  |  |  | User B | 20 |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000004-process |  |  | User H | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000004-process |  |  |  |  |  |  | User M | 20 |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000004-process |  |  |  |  |  |  | User N | 30 |  |  |  |  |
| COB-0000000004-process |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | User O | 20 |  |  |
| COB-0000000004-process |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | User J | 30 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by combining '`group by`' and '`SUM()`' with multiple `case when clause` as shown below.

```
select Case_,
       max(case when Queue = 'Branch_Maker' then User_ end) as 'Branch_Maker User',
       SUM(case when Queue = 'Branch_Maker' then TAT end) as 'Branch_Maker TAT',
       MAX(case when Queue = 'Branch_Checker' then User_ end) as 'Branch_Checker User',
       SUM(case when Queue = 'Branch_Checker' then TAT end) as 'Branch_Checker TAT',
       MAX(case when Queue = 'Compliance' then User_ end) as 'Compliance User',
       SUM(case when Queue = 'Compliance' then TAT end) as 'Compliance TAT'
from mytable
group by Case_, User_
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/U5OEyo6e)

Comment: thanks for the help this work as expected, can you help in additional part for the same question, how we can show one case per row and not to repeat the row, means the user and TAT column must be dynamic, like for case COB-001 , there are 4 branch maker and for COB-004 there is one branch maker, so COB-001 must have 8 columns one for branch maker username and one for respective TAT,

Comment: Glad to hear :) regarding your request not sure I understand it, Its an idea to post new question with more insights.